# Regex for (... Excludes-> \([\s\S]+\) ...)?

Tags: javascript, regex

I use

[a JavaScript regular expression tester](http://regexpal.com/)

to figure out my problem.

`\([\s\S]+\)` for `(foo (foo bar) bar) foo`

matches `(foo (foo bar) bar)`

Fine.

Now, I need a regex to match `(foo bar)`

So, what I need  is like  `(... Excludes-> \([\s\S]+\) ...)`

What is the regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
> '(foo (foo bar) bar) foo'.match(/\([^()]+\)/)
["(foo bar)"]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for another answer. This really fill my needs!